# How to search askubuntu.com on the fly (like google search)

Tags: support, search

In Google search we can see search results on the fly while we type. How to do this in askubuntu.com ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Goto ask advice @  https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask/advice?

[image]